# mpd httpd streaming not working

Tags: streaming, mpd

I have installed mpd and configured it to work flawlessly with gmpc locally.
I also use mpdroid on my phone and I want to stream music from my library to the phone.

The music control from mpdroid works without a glitch. But when i try to stream from mpd no sound comes of phone and connection is not established.

here is my mpd.conf file

```
#user               "mpd"
bind_to_address     "0.0.0.0"
audio_output {
    type        "alsa"
    name        "Sound Card"
    device      "hw:0,0"    # optional
    format      "44100:16:2"    # optional
    mixer_device    "default"   # optional
    mixer_control   "PCM"       # optional
    mixer_index "0"     # optional
}
audio_output {
    type        "httpd"
    name        "My HTTP Stream"
    encoder     "lame"      # optional, vorbis or lame
    port        "8000"
    quality     "2.0"           # do not define if bitrate is defined
#   bitrate     "128"           # do not define if quality is defined
    format      "44100:16:1"
}
mixer_type          "software"
```

and this is mpd.log

```
Mar 09 00:17 : player_thread: played "English Songs/Music/OSTs/(500) Days of Summer[Complete with Bonus Soundtracks][2009]/10 - Feist - Mushaboom.mp3"
Mar 09 00:26 : output: Failed to enable "My HTTP Stream" [httpd]: Failed to bind to '[::]:8000': Address already in use
Mar 09 00:26 : avahi: Service 'Music Player' successfully established.
Mar 09 00:26 : ffmpeg/mp3: Header missing
Mar 09 00:26 : ffmpeg/mp3: Could not find codec parameters (Audio: mp3, 0 channels, s16)
Mar 09 00:26 : ffmpeg/mp3: Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Mar 09 00:26 : ffmpeg/mp3: Header missing
Mar 09 00:27 : output: Failed to enable "My HTTP Stream" [httpd]: Failed to bind to '[::]:8000': Address already in use
```

Help Please!

Comment: try to disable bind_to_address